# Interference and Fermat's principle

Tags: optics, interference, variational-principle, huygens-principle

Fermat's principle states that light always takes the path for which the optical length is stationary.

\begin{align}
\delta\int n(\vec{r}) \:\mathrm ds = 0.
\end{align}

Furthermore, it is equivalent to Huygens' principle. Huygens' principle states that each point on a wavefront is the source of a new spherical wave. Huygens's principle is often used to describe interference patterns. How would you describe interference patterns with Fermat's principle?

Comment: The related wiki article might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle#Equivalence_to_Huygens'_construction

Comment: contrary to what you are saying above it is *NOT* equivalent to Huygens' principle.

Comment: I am not looking for proof of equivalency. My question is whether it is possible to describe interference with Fermat's principle.